# ODataProxy - ODataReader - Uncaught TypeError: b.getSuccess is not a function (MVC)

Tags: ext.net

I'm trying with EXT.NET MVC, I have a Grid, and a Store using ODataProxy, but I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: b.getSuccess is not a function

```
.Proxy(
    Html.X().ODataProxy()
        .Url("http://localhost:61460/Personas/")
        .Reader(
            Html.X().ODataReader().RootProperty("value")
        )
)
```

Can anyone help me with this error, if anybody have an example using ODataProxy I would apreciate it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The problem is being discussed in [the Ext.NET forums](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?49491).